# Google Script Reference Error

Tags: google-apps-script, referenceerror

In Google Sheets, I have a long list of names in column A, and tags in column B. What I want to accomplish with my function is to return only those values that I have stored in the functions list variable.

Currently I have a `ReferenceError` in my script project, and I don't know why.

Help would be appreciated.

```
function myFunction(cellInput) {
  var input = cellInput;
  var list = " word 1; word 2; word-3; word 4; word6; word-7;";
  var splitted_input = input.split("; ");    
  var splitted_list = list.split("; ");  

  var result = "";    
  for (var inc1 = 0; inc1 < splitted_list.length; inc1++) {
    for (var inc2 = 0; inc2 < splitted_input.length; inc2++) {
      var resSet = new Set(result.split("; "));
      if(splitted_list[inc1] == splitted_input[inc2] && !resSet.has(splitted_input[inc2])) {
        result = result + splitted_input[inc2] + "; ";
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: On which line you are getting reference error ?

Comment: Although I cannot understand about "a reference error in google sheets", from your script, I noticed a following issue. [``Set``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [``Set.prototype.has()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) were added from ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Unfortunately, Google Apps Script doesn't support ES6 yet. So in your script, I think that an error occurs at ``var resSet = new Set(result.split("; "));``. Is this related to your issue?